# Can we change op-amp inputs when using virtual ground?

Tags: operational-amplifier

It may be some kind of stupid question and i'm sorry if it is. Let's say that we have ideal non-inverting op-amp and we use virtual ground to solve the **Vo** value. But what if we change inputs? Does it really matter in ideal case?[image]

Answer (score 3):

Neither of your circuits have a virtual ground.

[image]

*Figure 1. The non-inverting input of the inverting op-amp is a virtual ground. Source: [Electrosome](https://electrosome.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Virtual-Ground-Inverting-Amplifier-Opamp.jpg).*

- In this case the op-amp output adjusts to bring the inverting-input to the same voltage as the non-inverting input.
- Since the non-inverting input is at ground potential then so is the inverting input.
- Since the inverting input is not *actually* connected to ground we call it "virtual ground". For all calculations we can consider it to be ground.

Comment: Ok, "virtual ground" is improper in my case, but as far as I know we assume potentials have the same values in that points.  Am I wrong?

Comment: The potentials only match if the feedback allows it. Your left diagram does because the feedback is negative. Your right circuit doesn't: the feedback is positive and the slightest difference in inputs will drive the output hard against one or other of the supply rails.

Answer (score 3):

Left side is a linear non-inverting amplifier.

Right side is a non-linear inverting comparator with positive feedback for hysteresis.

There is no comparison in performance.

**Rules:**  *Virtual ground* or **0V differential inputs only applies to non-saturated outputs** which could be the case for the left side only.  It NEVER applies to saturated outputs.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you are really asking, but one of your circuits has negative feedback, and the other positive.  Those will give two *totally different* results.

And no, Vo/Vi absolutely does not equal 1 + R1/R2 in the second case.  I can't even imagine how you think changing the polarity of the feedback wouldn't change the result drastically.  Go back and actually understand the equation and the conditions under which it applies.  Don't just blindly plug things into formulas you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

First off, a virtual ground is only talked about in the context of an inverting circuit using an operational amplifier, where the inverting input stays at the same potential as the non inverting input **and** the latter input is wired to ground.

Second your leftmost schema describes a non-inverting amplifier and the rightmost one a Schmidt trigger, which is what you get if you swap the inputs of the former.